# How do I change my gnome Ubuntu key-binding work as emacs?

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, gnome, hotkeys

, Hello, everyone

How can I change editing key-binding in Gnome on Ubuntu, and make it work like Emacs?

Eg. When I'm chat with my friend, and I want to use **Ctrl-a Ctrl-k** to move my cursor go to the left of current line, and then cut current line, as OSX or Emacs.
By default in Gnome Ubuntu, **Ctrl-a** is for "select all" and **ctrl-k** for nothing.

Where does this key binding define? And how can I change this?

I tried **gnome-keybinding-properties** and **gsettings**, find nothing.

Maybe I have to compile something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer on an interesting bug report

This report show me two different way to change the key scheme on old and newer Gnome

I tried this on Ubuntu 11.10 ( with Gnome 3), it works!

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Emacs"
```

If `gsettings` dosen't work, the following one may be available

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme -t string Emacs
```

[The bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gconf/+bug/812595)

Comment: This link [Gnome tweak tool](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeTweakTool) give a much more easy way to set emacs key bind.

Answer (score 5):

1. Use the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Open theme tab
3. Change the keybind theme to `emacs`

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details here: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Ctrl__bar_in_Mozilla

This page has the key bindings, which is very handy.

Comment: That page has nothing on it, are you sure you posted the right link?